# Problem with outputting data with AngularJS on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently struggling to understand what mistake I've made when writing up the code. I am just trying to get the initial array values to show up where the table data would be but i'm getting no luck.

Here is the HTML section for the code;

```
<body ng-controller="bookingController">
<h1>National Car Pool Company booking page</h1>
<div ng-show="!isEditing">
    <form>
        <p>Search for bookings <input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>
    </form>
    <p>
        Here are your current bookings;
    </p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Taxi ID</th>
                <th>Route</th>
                <th>Car Size</th>
                <th>Is Taxi Full?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="booking in bookings | filter:search">
                <td>{{booking.id}}</td>
                <td>{{booking.taxiRoute}}</td>
                <td>{{booking.taxiSize}}</td>
                <td>{{booking.taxiNoOfSeats}}</td>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="remove(Booking)">Remove Booking</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the JS file;

```
angular.module("itsBooking").controller("bookingController", function ($scope) { // Array of Bookings
$scope.bookings = [
    {
        id: 1,
        route: "October Business Development trip 2020",
        size: 9,
        noOfSeats: 6
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        route: "October Business Development trip 2020",
        size: 6,
        noOfSeats: 2
    }
];
```

This is an image of the webpage;

[Snap of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJZLp.png)

Any help would be fantastic, thank you

SM

**EDIT**

This was my previous version, in which it was working:

My HTML file;

```
   <p>Search for itineraries <input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>
    </form>
    <p>
        Here are your current itineraries
    </p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Itinerary Name</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Purpose</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="itinerary in itineraries | filter:search">
                <td>{{itinerary.id}}</td>
                <td>{{itinerary.itiName}}</td>
                <td>{{itinerary.destination}}</td>
                <td>{{itinerary.purpose}}</td>
                <td>{{itinerary.startDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                <td>{{itinerary.endDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="remove(itineraryItem)">Remove itinerary</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and my JS file;

```
angular.module("itsItinerary").controller("itineraryController", function ($scope) {    // Array of Itinerarys
    $scope.itineraries = [
        {
        id: 1,
        itiName: "October Business Development trip 2020",
        destination: "Germany",
        purpose: "Work",
        startDate: new Date("2020-10-03"),
        endDate: new Date("2020-10-10")
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        itiName: "November Client-site visit 2020",
        destination: "America",
        purpose: "Work",
        startDate: new Date("2020-11-05"),
        endDate: new Date("2020-11-08")
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        itiName: "January Scoping visit 2021",
        destination: "China",
        purpose: "Work",
        startDate: new Date("2021-01-15"),
        endDate: new Date("2021-01-23")
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

That scope looks like it's holding JSON type of data.
From my experience, which is not vast by any means, I've learned the keys have to be between "".
I have modified the relevant piece of your code:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"route": "October Business Development trip 2020",
"size": 9,
"noOfSeats": 6
}, 
{
"id": 2,
"route": "October Business Development trip 2020",
"size": 6,
"noOfSeats": 2
}
];
```

Could you give it a try?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.

I've tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately.
I had a previous version working using the same format I had posted and it was working, just wouldn't work when I tried it on this application

**Just posting the previous version now

Comment: So basically it's not showing any data?
Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors at all which is strange, I have just added an image of the webpage to the post.

But yes is the answer, done it times before just not sure why it's not working now

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace by following code:

```
var app = angular.module("itsBooking", []);
app.controller("bookingController", function($scope) { // Array of Bookings
$scope.bookings = [
    {
        id: 1,
        route: "October Business Development trip 2020",
        size: 9,
    noOfSeats: 6
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        route: "October Business Development trip 2020",
        size: 6,
        noOfSeats: 2
    }
]});
```

Also, in the html below change:

```
<body ng-app="itsBooking" ng-controller="bookingController">
```

Not sure where you have added ng-app on the html, but that is important one here. Also, one more issue I found out was function on the controller was not properly closed.

Similary, your matching of the properties is not correct:
**route** - in js to **booking.taxiRoute** in html.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello thanks for taking time to respond.

I've got the ng-app='ItsApp' included within the html tag so that should be fine.

The reason the function isn't closed was just because I took out a snippet, just got the syntax wrong to quickly close it, apologies

I have tried matching up properties and it's not working, currently booking.route is now route in js file etc..

Comment: @Davide in the code above you state that your app is named `itsBooking` but in this comment you state `ng-app='ItsApp'`. This is just a heads-up.

Comment: I have a .js file with angular.module("itsApp", ["itsBooking"]) 

I assumed I used itsApp in the html ng-app tag and the itsBooking the controller file?

Comment: @Davide You can first try to run it as individual app "itsBooking" rather then making using it as dependent. Can you check if that's working for you? I did try to run the code I had posted and it was working fine for me.

Comment: @Apurva I'm a little confused, I have changed myApp to itsBookings and pasted your code into the controller as the only code and it's still not showing up

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is missing now in your code. But here's the sample I created for you http://tpcg.io/o7RF6T .If you preview, you can see everythings working fine.